# Jasmine spyOn function that is not a method of an object

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

How do I spyOn a function that is not a method of an object. In my situation, `callMe` is also NOT on the `window` object - it is a dependency that is loaded via angular.

```
if (X) {
  callMe('hello');
}
```

Comment: when you say "it's loaded via angular" can I assume you are saying it's inject into your controller/service/whatever?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a spy object with the `jasmine.createSpy` method. Given a spy object is a regular JavaScript object, you can use this spy object to override your `callMe` function, in order to spy on it.

```
function callMe() {
    // implementation
}

describe('an example block', function() {
    it('creates a spy', function() {
        callMe = jasmine.createSpy('callMe');
        callMe();
        expect(callMe).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

From the [Jasmine 2.5 documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EcreateSpy%3C/code%3E):

> When there is not a function to spy on, `jasmine.createSpy` can create a “bare” spy. This spy acts as any other spy – tracking calls, arguments, etc. But there is no implementation behind it. Spies are JavaScript objects and can be used as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a spy and pass that to your controller. Check the following code:

```
beforeEach(
        inject(function (_$controller_) {
            myController = _$controller_('myControllerName', {
                callMe: jasmine.createSpy('callMe');
            });
        })
    );
```

This will basically replace the callMe object that you inject into your controller.